# Why isn't my Wordpress custom route returning data out of the database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress, endpoint

The code below is my custom endpoint where I am trying to grab data out of my `saic3_LibraryIndex` database.

```
<?php
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {

    register_rest_route('libraries/v1', '/all', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'retrieve_libraries'
    ) );

} );

function retrieve_libraries( $data ) {

    global $saic3_LibraryIndex;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Library`";
    $list = $saic3_LibraryIndex->get_results($query);
    return $list;

}
```

In my javascript I am running an ajax call on page load to attempt to dynamically populate the page based off of the info in the db. For now I am just using this call to make sure that I am getting something back.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 


jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-json/libraries/v1",
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        failure: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

The route is hitting as a success and not giving me a 404 but the response I am getting back has no data in it. The response is just

```
{namespace: "libraries/v1", routes: {…}, _links: {…}}
     namespace
     :
     "libraries/v1"
     routes
     :
     /libraries/v1
     :
     endpoints
     :
     [{…}]
     methods
     :
     ["GET"]
 namespace
 :
 "libraries/v1"
 _links
 :
 {self: "{`my-url-.com`/wp-json/libraries/v1"}
 __proto__
 :
 Object
 /libraries/v1/all
 :
 endpoints
 :
 [{…}]
 methods
 :
 ["GET"]
 namespace
 :
 "libraries/v1"
 _links
 :
 {self: "`my-url-.com`/wp-json/libraries/v1/all"}
 __proto__
 :
 Object
 __proto__
 :
 Object
 _links
 :
 up
 :
 [{…}]
 __proto__
 :
 Object
 __proto__
 :
 Object
```

I am brand new to WordPress so any help on this would be greatly appreciated. From what I was told the database was named saic3_LibraryIndex which from my thinking would take the place of wpdb. I tried switching it to wpdb and just using this call to grab the local posts but that still gives me the same response in the console. I am almost certain that endpoint is written incorrectly just not sure how to write it correctly.

Comment: It looks like you're `return`ing rather than `echo`ing a JSON encoded response in your `retrieve_libraries` callback.

Comment: Looking at [the Wordpress REST Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/), you may need to wrap your data with a call to `rest_ensure_response`. Try returning `rest_ensure_response($list)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **SOLVED**

Since I was trying to connect to another database outside of wpdb I needed to create a new instance of wpdb like so...

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('libraries/v1', '/all', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'retrieve_libraries'
    ) );
} );

function retrieve_libraries( $data ) {
    $second_db = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, "saic3_LibraryIndex", DB_HOST);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Library`";
    $list = $second_db->get_results($query);
    return $list;
}
```